# How can I solve the problem "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my HTML & JavaScript project.

When I run my code, I have an error which is

> "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null".

I tried to solve this problem, and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038225/how-do-i-solve-this-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null-error), but I can't understand because I'm beginner of programming, and I'm not good at English.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        var wordlist = [ "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" ];
        var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length);
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");

        for(i = 0; i < wordlist[rannum].length; i++) {
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            x.setAttribute("value", "");
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you help me to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be I am missing something, but the fiddle works for me.  What is the expected behavior?  http://jsfiddle.net/Lh895pd6/

Comment: Try this:

    <html>
       <head> 
       </head>
       <body>
          <script language="javascript">
           var wordlist = [ "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" ];
           var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length);
           var x = document.createElement("INPUT");

           for(i = 0; i < wordlist[rannum].length; i++) {
              x.setAttribute("type", "text");
              x.setAttribute("value", "");
              document.body.appendChild(x);
           }

          </script>
       </body>
    </html>

Comment: @Gyumeijie Thank you! It works! But is there no way to code `<script>` on `<body>`?

Comment: Yes, you can also use the `defer` attribute of <script>.

Comment: @Gyumeijie What do you mean to use the defer attribute?

Comment: <script language="javascript" defer>

Comment: For more information, you can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. There several ways to fix the issue:

1. You can specify [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) attribute in the script tag.
2. You can wrap the code with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event which is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed.
3. You can place the script at the end of the `body`.

**Attribute** [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

By creating the input outside the loop you are referencing the same element in each iteration in the loop. You have to create the element inside the loop

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" defer>
        var wordlist = [ "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" ];
        var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length);
        for(i = 0; i < wordlist[rannum].length; i++) {
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            x.setAttribute("value", "");
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work when I copy your code, paste it, and run my code. It works on snippet, But it doesn't work on my code. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @HoseongJeon, as we are unable to see your actual code, we can not do much. We can only try to find the solution based on the code you have posted here......thanks.

Comment: @HoseongJeon, by noticing the comment, I have updated the answer....please check

Comment: @HoseongJeon, you are most welcome....:)